# ZXing.Net.Mobile view does not stretch for UWP in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, zxing

I use [ZXing.Net.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile) ZXingScannerView in a Xamarin.Forms application. I test it with Android API 21+ and Windows Mobile 10. While in Android the camera stream expands to the boundaries of the scanner view perfectly, this is not true for UWP. No matter that the emulator size or resolution. I"ve also tried with a real windows phone device and the issue still appears.

I place the ZXingScannerView in a content page similar to this:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
        ...
        <Grid
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <zxing:ZXingScannerView
                x:Name="zxing"
                Result="{Binding ScannerResult, Mode=TwoWay}"
                IsScanning="{Binding ScannerScanning}"
                IsVisible="{Binding ScannerVisible}"
                IsAnalyzing="{Binding ScannerAnalyzing}"
                ScanResultCommand="{Binding ScannedCommand}"/>
            <v:MainPageZXingOverlayView />
        </Grid>
        ...
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Also I've noticed that the [view .xaml](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Source/ZXing.Net.Mobile.WindowsUniversal/ZXingScannerControl.xaml#L19) has a capture element set to Stretch="Fill"

```
 <CaptureElement  
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        x:Name="captureElement"  
        Stretch="Fill" />
```

also in [view .cs](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Source/ZXing.Net.Mobile.WindowsUniversal/ZXingScannerControl.xaml.cs#L228)

```
// *after* the preview is setup, set this so that the UI layout happens
// otherwise the preview gets stuck in a funny place on screen
captureElement.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
```

Anyone experiencing the same problem or have a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

> While in Android the camera stream expands to the boundaries of the scanner view perfectly, this is not true for UWP. No matter that the emulator size or resolution. I"ve also tried with a real windows phone device and the issue still appears.

The preview resolution was set based on camera resolution when the camera start to scan.

For your requirement, you could expand preview to the boundaries via custom camera resolution. Please refer to the following code :

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
    {
        CameraResolutionSelector = HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate
    };
    var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
    scanner.AutoFocus();
    var result = await scanner.Scan(options);
    if (result != null)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Scanned Barcode: " + result.Text);
}
CameraResolution HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate(List<CameraResolution> availableResolutions)
{
    //Don't know if this will ever be null or empty
    if (availableResolutions == null || availableResolutions.Count < 1)
        return new CameraResolution() { Width = 800, Height = 600 };

    //Debugging revealed that the last element in the list
    //expresses the highest resolution. This could probably be more thorough.
    return availableResolutions[availableResolutions.Count - 1];
}
```

[image]

**Update**

> Note that i'm using the `ZXingScannerView` itself, but not the built-in wrappers. I've updated my question to be more clear.

If you use `ZXingScannerView`, you could also modify `ZXingScannerView`  Options in the code behind.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
    {
        CameraResolutionSelector = HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate
    };
    zxing.Options = options;
}
CameraResolution HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate(List<CameraResolution> availableResolutions)
{
    //Don't know if this will ever be null or empty
    if (availableResolutions == null || availableResolutions.Count < 1)
        return new CameraResolution() { Width = 800, Height = 600 };

    //Debugging revealed that the last element in the list
    //expresses the highest resolution. This could probably be more thorough.
    return availableResolutions[availableResolutions.Count - 1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I’ve tried your suggestion but had no luck with it. In the same source file I see:            
`captureElement.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;`
and this is what is not respected I think in UWP, although I don’t know why.

Comment: It works in my side when  I use  600*800 camera resolution.

Comment: Note that i'm using the `ZXingScannerView` itself, but not the built-in wrappers. I've updated my question to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks, i've already tried your solution modifying the code to fit my scenario, but it does not work for me. Using a custom resolution with the appropriate height/width ratio could make the things better, but does not solve my problem. Also i could choose only form the available resolutions and in my case i have a limited number according the debugger (only 3). Forcing custom resolution like 600*800 throws an exception. My pain is why after setting `<CaptureElement Stretch="Fill" /> and captureElement.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;` (ZXingScannerControl .xaml / .cs) it does not respect that.

Comment: This  setting `<CaptureElement Stretch="Fill" /> and captureElement.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill/>` works well. However , your camera steam's rendering could not fill in  `CaptureElement` in original resolution.

Comment: But on Android it always stretch to fill the whole space at any resolution. While on UWP it never do that, not matter the resolution.

Comment: Yep, If you think this is a obvious issue, you can submit your feedback [here](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues).

Comment: Thanks for the effort.